How to prop drill down through a LInk component in nextJS14
i was wondering if anyone could advise me on the best way to get data passed through a Link component? I have identified the parent component that i wish to lift up the state to, in this case its the DropDownModal component. From there the data has to pass down through two components on each branch. My problem is one branch is AvatarBlock, which is a component, thats fine, the problem is my second branch which is a link that takes me to the account page. Because it isnt a component im not sure how to navigate through it with prop drilling.
export function DropDownModal() {
// ------------ i plan on lifting up the state here.
  return (
    <DropdownMenu>
      <DropdownMenuTrigger>
        <AvatarBlock />       // ----------------------- 1st branch
      </DropdownMenuTrigger>
      <DropdownMenuContent>
        <DropdownMenuLabel>My Account</DropdownMenuLabel>
        <DropdownMenuSeparator />
        <DropdownMenuItem>
          <Link href="/Account">Profile Page</Link>    // ------------------ 2nd branch
        </DropdownMenuItem>

        <DropdownMenuItem>Log out</DropdownMenuItem>
      </DropdownMenuContent>
    </DropdownMenu>
  );
}

I have tried (naively) to pass through the data as props in the normal way but the state variable is showing as null once i use it in the component where i want to access it. Any help on this would be appreciated.

I don't recommend passing data thru link, even if it's supported, you lose the data if you go to the destination directly instead of thru clicking the link.
With next, I don't see a Link prop for you to pass down data, so I would use Link query (for example a ID) instead.
<Link
   href={{
   pathname: '/about',
   query: { name: 'test' },
   }}
>

Then you fetch the data on destination page load.
Alternative is either using react context or something like redux.
